# How to assign a function value to a variant if that function may return an object?

Tags: vba

I'm assigning a value to a variable, where that value is either a number or an object instance depending on the result of a server request, as follows:

```
Sub assignVar()

Dim v As Variant

v = getValue

End Sub

Function getValue() As Variant

Dim result As Boolean

result = PostSomethingToServer()
If result Then
    getValue = 1
Else
    Set getValue = New Dictionary
    getValue.Add "a", 1
End If

End Function
```

This works fine if I call `assignVar(true)`, but if I call `assignVar(false)` then I get the error:

```
Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment
```

which is to be expected, because if `getValue()` returns an object, it should be assigned as `set v = getValue`.  But if I write it this way, then I get a `Type mismatch` error because I'm trying to assign an integer using a `Set` statement.

How can I make sure that `v` gets assigned correctly for either return value of `getValue()`?

Answer (score 1):

For now I'm resolving this by adding a `ReturnValue` class:

```
Option Explicit

Public value As Variant
Public valueIsObject As Boolean

Public Sub setup(value As Variant)

If IsObject(value) Then
    Set Me.value = value
    valueIsObject = True
Else
    Me.value = value
    valueIsObject = False
End If

End Sub
```

This way, I can rewrite the test methods as follows:

```
Sub assignVar()

Dim v As Variant
Dim rv as ReturnValue

Set rv = getValue

If rv.valueIsObject Then
    Set v = rv.value
Else
    v = rv.value
End If

End Sub

Function getValue() As ReturnValue

Dim result As Boolean
Dim dict as Dictionary

result = PostSomethingToServer()

set getValue=new ReturnValue

If result Then
    getValue.setup 1
Else
    Set dict = New Dictionary
    dict.Add "a", 1
    getValue.setup dict
End If

End Function
```