# Convert to object in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a very strange problem. There is a variable Item of type Variant that contains an array of dictionaries. It comes from another module and I cannot change it. I want to assign it to a dictionary value

```
Dim MyDict as New Dictionary
set MyDict(key)=Item
```

This gives an error "Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment"

Yet this code works fine:

```
Dim MyDict as New Dictionary
Dim oTemp as Object
set oTemp=Item
set MyDict(key)=oTemp
```

Why is it happening and can I do it without using oTemp? There is no CObj function in VBA.

UPD: I have simplified the code above to make it more clear but here is the actual code:

```
Dim item As Variant
Dim JSONDict As New Dictionary
Dim oTemp As Object
Dim i As Integer

Set JSON = ParseJson(JsonString)
For Each item In JSON.Items
    For i = 1 To item.Count
         Set oTemp = item(i)
         Set JSONDict(item(i)("isbn13")) = oTemp
  Next
```

Next
This code works fine but breaks if I don't use the intermediate oTemp variable. I do not understand why.
Here are screens of Local Window

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Examples of the data and your set operations would be immensely helpful here. Hard to solve this without seeing `Item`.

Comment: I've tested with `Item` as a `Variant/Array/Dictionary` and `Set MyDIct(key) = Item` works for me.  There may be something more going on in the "other module".  can you post some detail of the type declarations etc in that module for Item?

Comment: Sample code to prove the point `Sub Demo()
        Dim MyDict As Dictionary
        Dim item As Variant
        Dim key As String
        Set MyDict = New Dictionary
        ReDim item(1 To 2)
        Set item(1) = New Dictionary
        Set item(2) = New Dictionary
        key = "key"
        item(1).Add key, "Item 1 Data"
        MyDict.Add key, vbNullString
        Set MyDict(key) = item
        Debug.Print MyDict(key)(1)(key)
    End Sub`

Comment: I get the error with `Dim d As New Dictionary, a : a = d`, but can't figure out a way to reproduce it with your code.

Comment: It would be nice to have the declarations of all the operands involved here. We'll take your word that `Item` is a `Variant` containing an *array of dictionaries*, but then if that's the case, `Set MyDict(key) = Item` is assigning *an array of dictionaries* to a `key` in `MyDict`, which doesn't sound at all like what you say you're trying to do.

Comment: I agree with @Mat'sMug. To get the dictionary, it should be `Set MyDict = Item(0)` if the dictionary array is 1D. And it helps to use the `Locals Window` while running the code line by line by pressing `F8` instead of `F5` so you will see the current value of `Item`, its bounds etc.

Comment: Please share locals window screenshot once error occured. Show the relevant variables unfolded.

Comment: `Option Explicit`

Comment: To all: I have added the actual code and a screenshot.

Comment: Have you tried `Let JSONDict(item(i)("isbn13")) = item(i)`? (`Let` instead of `Set`)  Also, is the error at compile time or runtime?  Is the Dictionary a `Scripting.Dictionary`?  Where does `ParseJson` come from?  Which JSON library are you using, or is it a custom routine?  Can you use `Dictionary.Add` instead of an assignment to `Item()`?  [Possibly relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46497229/2877364).

Comment: Thanks for adding the extra info.  However that's not enough.  Please show the watch window shots of variable `JSON` expanded to show at least one item.  The line of code `For Each item In JSON.Items` implies `JSON` is a dictionary (not an array of dictionaries as you claimed).  And post whatever details you can of the library that includes `ParseJson`

Comment: Is [this](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON) the library you are using?

Comment: chris neilsen: I added the watch window. JSON is a dictionary, values are arrays of dictionaries: see the use json("data")(1)("id") in immediate window. 
I think I use the same library as you posted (it is not my code but looks similar)
All this still does not explain why I cannot add the element [json("data")(1)] to my dictionary directly but have to assign it to an object first.